# No result for select sum query using ActiveRecord (bigint column)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table called banners with a column id (bigint) and click (bigint) and user_id (bigint)

In the console, or even the controller when I use the following request :

```
Banner.select("sum(click) as clicks").where(user_id: 5)
```

I get :

```
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Banner id: nil>]>
```

I copied the same resulting request in phppgadmin SQL :

```
SELECT  sum(click) as clicks FROM "banners" WHERE "banners"."user_id" = 5
```

and it works, but with active record it does not !!?

Rails version : 5.1.4

**UPDATE**

I tried `Banner.select("sum(id)")` and it gives me `=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Banner id: nil>]>`

With users table : `User.select("sum(id)")` it gives : `=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil, sum: 0.1e1>]>`

It's weird as it works for one table and not others... I even switched to another project and tried different tables, I get the same behavior.

Comment: Just try to access with `Banner.select("sum(click) as clicks").where(user_id: 5).first.clicks`

Comment: @Manishh doesn't work either :( i updated my question with more info

Comment: Make sure you are using same `database` in both the cases, also try following `Banner.where(user_id: 5).sum(:click)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding group clause on id.

```
Banner.select("sum(click) as clicks").where(user_id: 5).group(:id)
```

It will return `ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Banner id: nil>, #<Banner id: nil>` and now when you call `.first.clicks` on this will give you desired output (sum of clicks). If you want id's as well you will have to specify id in select clause.

Comment: @Marnishh by doing group, it just gives a relation of Banner objects as you see, and if you do .first.clicks it gives the click column's value of the first object alone

Comment: I don't understand, I just created a new brand rails app and created a table banners with a columns click, I added two records one with value click=3 and another with click=5, when I do your request it shows 1 in both record (first and last)

Answer (score 0):

If

```
banners = Banner.select("sum(click) as clicks").where(user_id: 5)
```

`banners.class` will be `Banner:ActiveRecord_Relation`, In order to fetch `clicks` you have to use `.first` or `.last` (As it will have only one element in it), like following

```
banners.last.clicks
```

You can verify it by using

```
Banner.where(user_id: 5).sum(:click)
```

Comment: I tried that in the console and it asks me to add group by id, when I do that it gives me the Banner:ActiveRecord_Relation as you said, but every object in it has the click of one row (not the sum/total)

Comment: from what I detected, rails add an order by clause to the request, which obligate to add the group by clause, do you have any idea how we to prevent the order by from being added ?

Comment: You may have something like `default_scope { order(id: :desc) }` in your Banner model. You can also check your query using `.to_sql` like `Banner.select("sum(click) as clicks").where(user_id: 5).to_sql`

Comment: No I have no default scope or whatever... look I just created a new brand app with a table banners and only one column called "click", when I do `banners = Banner.select("sum(click) as clicks")` it shows `SELECT  sum(click) as clicks FROM "banners" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]` and the result is `=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Banner id: nil>]>` right ? now when I try to access `banners.first.clicks` it runs another request `SELECT  sum(click) as clicks FROM "banners" ORDER BY "banners"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]`

Comment: at the same time it fails : `ERROR:  column "banners.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`,  this error is because of the second request has ORDER BY on it ! it's generated by rails, and frankly I was not expecting a second request to happen + as you see the second request is retrieving only one record count